# $Z(D_{2n})=\{e\}$ if $n\ge 3$ is odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am tasked with proving that for $n\in\mathbb{N}\ge 3,$

$$Z(D_{2n})=\{e\}$$
where $Z(G)$ is the set of all elements of a group $G$ that commute with every element of $G$, and the Dihedral group is defined to be
$$D_{2n}=\{r,s|r^n=s^2=1, rs=sr^{-1}\}$$

Clearly the identity element is always in $Z(G)$ for all groups $G$.  With the Dihedral group of order $2n$, if we simply look the subgroup $C_{2n}$, since this is a commutative group, all elements of the subgroup $C_{2n}$ commute with each other.  Now I have to look at the remaining elements of $D_{2n}$, the reflectional elements, $r^is$.
For the product of a reflection and a rotation to be commutative, it must satisfy
$$r^is*r^j=r^j*r^is$$
but by the property of the Dihedral group, $r^{i-j}s=r^{j+i}s$.  So then $i-j=j+i$  This should finish the problem, I feel, but I just get that $i=j=0$, which is not helping...How do I finish?   What's really annoying me is I haven't even used the faact that we have an odd order group.  Where am I going awry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculations seem mostly correct, but from $r^{i-j}s=r^{i+j}s$ you can only conclude that $i-j=i+j$ modulo $n$, since $r^n=1$. By adding $j$ and substracting $i$ you get the condition that $2j=0$ mod $n$. This is impossible if $n$ is odd since $j<n$.
If $n$ is even, the element $r^{n/2}$ is an element of the center (essentially by the above calculation).